# The event is not subscribed by method in Angular (modal window)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, events, modal-dialog

I have modal window and component where this modal window called. When i try to close this modal window, method that need to close it - don't invoked, because of this method starts when event is emited. But method subscription doesn't happen.

```
export class TakeOrderFormComponent implements OnInit
{
  @ViewChild('orderSucModal') orderSuccessModal: OrderSuccessComponent;
  orderSuccessRef: BsModalRef;

  constructor(private orderService: OrderService, private cartService: CartService,
              private modalService: BsModalService, private router: Router)
  {
  }

  openCartModal(orderId: number): void
  {
    this.orderSuccessModal.loadOrder(orderId);
    this.orderSuccessRef = this.modalService.show(this.orderSuccessModal.template, {ignoreBackdropClick: true});
  }

  hideSucModal(): void
  {
    console.log('in parent start')
    this.orderSuccessRef.hide();
    console.log('in parent stop')
  } ...
```

This is code of modal window in main block. And here method `hideSucModal()` don't invoked.

```
<app-order-success
  #orderSucModal
  (hideModal)="hideSucModal()">
</app-order-success>
```

All modal window code

```
    <ng-template #orderSuccess class="modal-md">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Ваше замовлення <b>№{{order.orderId}}</b> успішно оброблено!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button (click)="hideModalClick()" class="btn btn-outline-success"
                type="button">Зрозуміло!
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

And here is logic of modal-component

```
export class OrderSuccessComponent
{
  @ViewChild('orderSuccess') template: TemplateRef<any>;
  @Output() hideModal: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();
  @Output() confirm: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();

  public order: Order = new Order();
  public dateAndTime: string[] = [];

  constructor(private orderService: OrderService, private router: Router)
  {
  }

  hideModalClick(): void
  {
    console.log('in child start')
    this.hideModal.emit();
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    console.log('in child stop');
  }...
```

Actually as I done some research, I think that method `hideSucModal()` can't subscribe to `hideModal` event. Any thoughts about this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make small refactoring:

*1) in core component*
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';

add in constructor
**constructor( ... ,private matDialog: MatDialog )**

to open modal window use
this.matDialog.open(OrderSuccessComponent, {data},width:'100%', height:'90%')

*2) in OrderSuccessComponent*

add in constructor
**constructor**( ... **,private dialogRef: MatDialogRef** )

and now you can call this.dialogRef.close() inside hideModalClick()

Pay attention different entities (MatDialog  vs MatDialogRef) used in core and child components!